# SQL 2008 Install gone bad!

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I've had a failed install of SQL 2008 on a windows server 2008 box and now when I try and uninstall the uninstall fails and asks me if I'd like to remove it from the list.

If I do a repair I get so many errors and I think I know where it went wrong now, but I can't fully uninstall it properly to try!

The first problem was I hadn't turned off UAC and I was trying to install as Domain Admin.

I then went to the box as a the local admin and it failed because we have a domain policy here that has a list of specific users that have rights to the "Manage auditing and security log " so that failed also, and this when it got into a right mess.

Is there any known method on how to fully remove SQL 2008? THis really is turning out to be the install from hell!

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967/en-us
http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/SQLServer2008InstallNightmare.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turning off UAC isn't required to install SQL, and being a domain admin is fine.  I installed all my machines with UAC enabled, and as a domain admin without issue.